# How can I get the value of the last top level expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, eval

Given a string of JS source code that contains multiple top level expressions, I'd like to evaluate all of them and get the value of the last one.

Getting the value of the other top level expressions would be a bonus.
I understand `eval` is dangerous.

I'm doing this in a limited context,
not part of a random public web page.

Also I am using Node and Electron
in case that matters.

Comment: Could you share an example of the code you want to eval and an example of the expected output?

Comment: eval_variant("3   4")   returns 4.   or even eval_variant("3   4") returns [3, 4]